# фиксированный ListView в ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, view, android-viewpager

У меня есть список слов. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы он отображался в ViewPager, для этого я использовал ListView, но мне нужно чтобы на одной "странице" слова отображались до низа экрана без прокрутки, следом пользователь переключается на другую страницу, чтобы увидеть там продолжение.

Главная проблема в том, что я не знаю как сообщить ViewPager сколько будет страниц, а также не знаю как сделать, чтобы ListView показывал на одной странице фиксированное количество слов в зависимости от размера экрана(без прокрутки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я могу вам посоветовать вариант которым я пользовался для решения подобной задачи. Вам нужно знать размер одного элемента вашего списка в listview и дальше знать точное кол-во слов которое нужно разместить в приложении. Дальше все просто, вы вытаскиваете размер layout на устройстве, отминусовываете тулбар если он есть, и дальше зная кол-во слов, размер одного элемента и размер вашего экрана выводите на экран определенное кол-во слов в списке.

Дальше с viewPager - все приблизительно так же. У вас есть кол-во слов, есть кол-во ваших списков которые будут вмещаться в вашем layout и дальше вы сообщаете вашему виджету что нужно создать кол-во вкладок эквивалентное кол-ву списков со словами.

Самое главное в решении вашей задачи правильно получить размер экрана и создать точное кол-во элементов списка для формирования самого списка. Как вариант вы можете создать функцию которая будет заполнять ваш список словами не основываясь на кол-ве слов, и дальше уже передавать данные по списку в viewPager. Для этого вам нужно получать данные о размере экрана и дальше просчитывать размер списка который будет размещен в вкладке.

Надеюсь я помог в решении вашей проблемы. Если будут вопросы - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

P.S. вот [ссылка](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/313848/Get-actual-screen-size-for-the-application-layout) по получению размера layout надеюсь поможет.

Comment: спасибо, у меня получилось)

Comment: хотя всё таки не получилось добиться того, чтобы listview был ровно по размеру экрана. попробовал вычислить высоту одного элемента и затем программно задать, но всё равно почему-то не влазит где-то на 20 пикселей.

Comment: @AndryMax, может не учли высоту статус бара? Если что вычисление тут можно подсмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400243

Comment: не понимаю что происходит... я пробовал использовать вычисления по вашей ссылке, они аналогичны тому что скинул Andrew Goroshko, так вот по ним к примеру получается высота 1608, и к примеру я задаю высоту элемента 134 и беру 12 элементов, как итог выходит за рамки почти на целый элемент. Вчера оставив коммент я пробовал взять высоту layout так view.getHeight, так вот по ней получается 1536 это 12 элементов с высотой 128 и тут выходит за рамки визуально на писклей так 20. Не понимаю, что не так может быть.

Comment: я понял. дело в том, что я не учёл dividerHeight в listview. и всё таки высоту надо брать так view.getHeight.